How to sudo as jenkins user using password for privilege escalation
I want to run configuration playbooks as well as automatic patching using ansible and jenkins on linux servers. I need centralized environment for patching and node configuration, I opted for Jenkins as I'm limited to open-source options.
Autopatching can be easily done by granting nopasswd sudo access to jenkins user for either apt or dnf or bash script which will do the job.
My question is - what about other stuff?
Our security policy doesn't allow nopasswd for all commands for users, so currently all ansible playbooks are ran with --ask-become-pass option, we provide our user's sudo password so ansible can do it's job.
I couldn't find any articles/tutorials about providing sudo credentials using Jenkins - is this even possible?

If you have a dedicated user added to the sudoers used for the jenkins user, you can create a credential in the jenkins settings for this user. Then you can select the Secret credential for usage with your jenkins script and don't have to include a password in your script or as userinput.
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'patching', 
 usernameVariable:'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {

// available as an env variable, but will be masked if you try to print it 
 out any which way
// note: single quotes prevent Groovy interpolation; expansion is by Bourne 
 Shell, which is what you want
sh 'echo $PASSWORD'
// also available as a Groovy variable
echo USERNAME
// or inside double quotes for string interpolation
echo "username is $USERNAME"
}

For more information see the credentials page from jenkins.
